# Create Service implementing ContainerAwareInterface

Tags: symfony

The service don't invoke setContainer when I extend ContainerAware or implement ContainerAwareInterface.

```
class CustomService implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

How can I use the container from my service without injection one?
Is it required to pass the container object to the constructor or a setter?

Comment: Is this your full class or just a subset? $this->container doesn't exists in your class. Please, show your "use" statements

Comment: Did you try to set the calls params in your service definition in order to call setContainer method passing service_container as argument ?

Answer (score 7):

Make a definition in your services.yml file

```
services:
    bundle.service_name: 
        class: ...
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```

Comment: I did exactly this, but now the entire app just hang

Comment: You have to put the service name inside coats:

services:
    bundle.service_name: 
        class: ...
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ '@service_container' ] ]

Answer (score 5):

Only implementing the `ContainerAware` or `ContainerAwareInterface` is not enough. You have to call a setter injection with the `service_container` as argument. **But injecting the complete container is not recommended.** Better inject only the services you really need.

Answer (score 5):

You have to put the service name inside quotes:

```
services:
    bundle.service_name: 
        class: ...
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ '@service_container' ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also [ContainerAwareTrait](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/master/ContainerAwareTrait.php) that you can use to implement ContainerAwareInterface.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a full implementaion of a container aware service.

**But be warned that injecting the whole container should be avoided.** It is best practice to inject only the needed components. See the [Law of Demeter - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) for more info on the subject.

To this end, this command will help you find all the available services :

```
# symfony < 3.0
php app/console debug:container

# symfony >= 3.0
php bin/console debug:container
```

Anyway, here's the full example.

The `app/config/services.yml` file:

```
app.my_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\MyService
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

The service class in `src/AppBundle/Service/MyService.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;

class MyService implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function useTheContainer()
    {
        // do something with the container
        $container = $this->container;
    }
}
```

And finaly your controller in `src/AppBundle/Controller/MyController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * My controller.
 */
class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="app_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $myService = $this->get('app.my_service');
        $myService->useTheContainer();

        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to automatically call `setContainer` on all classes that have the `ContainerAwareInterface` (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754257/1386610)):

```yaml
# services.yaml
services:
  _instanceof:
    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface:
      calls:
        - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```