# Symfony3 save login Timestamp in database after authentication success

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

Well, the title says it all. I have a login form which works fine. But what I have to do is to save the timestamp when the user successfully logs in in addition to a field which stores the timestamp when the database record is changed. So these are two different fields. I have found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922516/symfony2-login-and-security) which does what I want. Unfortunately the class ContainerAware is not present in Symfony3 so I don't know how to get a EntityManager instance into my Handler. I'm pretty sure, that there is a simple solution, but I just can't find it.

With help of the hint from @micguo I got a step further. Here is my code so far:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface{

use ContainerAwareTrait;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface::onAuthenticationSuccess()
 */
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {
    $token->getUser()->setAnmeldat(new \DateTime("now"));
    $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->flush();
    
    return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('/auth/bnme'));
}

}
```

But when I try to log in, Symfony throws an Exception:

> Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object .

What is wrong here?

Comment: but what the question is? To store Timestamp value on login? Just edit the Entity and re-create the table, so it has it's field, and populate it on login... What is a complication here?

Comment: I have to use two different database fields for this. One field for changes on the record and one other for the login timestamp

Comment: Raistlin, good input, just put this additional information to the question itself, be more specific. Thank you.

Comment: Since you're registering your handler in your configuration, simply use the `arguments` option to pass your Entity Manager.There's just no need for the container at all in there.

Comment: Great! That did the job. I have to work on redirecting to the next page but the timestamp is written to the database. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ContainerAwareTrait instead

---

To use ContainerAwareTrait, you need to make a definition in your services.yml file.

[Create Service implementing ContainerAwareInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484849/create-service-implementing-containerawareinterface)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I tried it but then got an exception: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object . I'll post the code in my question above