# How can I create a new MyService() with autowire?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, symfony4

*I love autowiring*, it's definitely the most elegant dependency management solution I've ever seen. I would love to also use it when instantiating new objects.

Consider the following service:

```
class MyService()
{
    public function __construct(Dependency1 $var1, Dependency99 $var99)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is when I use it:

```
class AnotherService
{
    public function buildServices(array $arrData)
    {
        $arrMyServices = [];
        foreach($arrData as $data) {

                                    // I want to autowire this!
            $arrMyServices[] = (new MyService($var1, $var99))
                                    ->loadData($data);
        }

        return $arrMyServices;
    }
}
```

The question is about the line below `// I want to autowire this!`. **I don't want to pass the dependency manually there**, but create a new auto-wired service. Ideally, I would call `$symfony->createMyService()` and get back a new instance of my service, autowired.

ATM I literally created a factory method like `createMyService()`, but it sucks big time. Is there a "Symfony" way to do that?

Edit: unfortunately it looks like I was not able to explain my question very well. My bad. Let's retry like this:

**How do you instantiate multiple service requiring various dependencies in a loop?** Please answer this specific question, thanks!

Comment: If you want to autowire a service, you do not use `new`, you declare the dependency in the  constructor for the service.

Comment: It seems you do not really understand auto-wiring. If your dependencies are automatically injected, you would not need to call something like `$symfony->createMyService()`. Which looks too similar to the service locator pattern, which is not what you do with dependency injection and auto-wiring.

Comment: It seems you do not really understood the question. My bad, I updated it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do that with autowiring.

If I have understood your question correctly, you have to declare your `MyService` as non shared (`shared: false` in `services.yaml`) and use the service container to instantiate a new `MyService` object on every cycle.

Ex:

```php
class AnotherService implement ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function buildServices()
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 99; ++$i) {
            // This will be a new instance on every cycle if shared is set to false
            yield $this->container->get(MyService::class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! This on its own is not enough, but it pointed me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484849/create-service-implementing-containerawareinterface A buon rendere, ciao!